# React redirect from a function inside App component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a function inside AppComponent as shown below.

```
login = () => {
this.setState({
  isLoggedIn : true
}, () => {
  localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
  // here i have to redirect to a different page
  // I dont have access to this.props.history since this function is inside AppComponent
});
```

}

I want to redirect to a different page. But I dont have access to props.history as this function is declared within the Appcomponent itself.

how can I make the function to redirect to a different component after updating the state.

Help much appreaciated.

Comment: [You could create a `history` object of your own and pass that to the `Router` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router), and then just use that object by itself. `history.push(location);`

Comment: Use Link in react router

Comment: Hi @Tholle, I did try your solution, but not working. I did create an instance history as shown below.

**import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
const history = createBrowserHistory();**

and when I try to do this history.push("/users"); not happens.

Comment: check out withRouter HOC of react-router-dom, it will inject history into ur component and then u can use it to redirect anywhere. Just wrap ur component as withRouter(AppComponent)

Comment: @ArungopanGopakumar You need to make sure you pass the `history` object to the `Router` as well. `<Router history={history}> ... </Router>`

Comment: Thank you so much @NomanHassan, WithRouter actually worked.